# IndexError: list index out of range when trying to print first element of list returned by a function

Tags: python, list

```py
def checkinputs():

    desc_list = []
    round_desc_list = []

    time.sleep(30)

    event_type = "input"
    event,output_list,desc_list,psbt,num_i = getevents()

    if num_i % 5 !=0 or num_i == 0:
        print(num_i)
        checkinputs()
    else:
        round_desc_list.append(desc_list[0])
        round_desc_list.append(desc_list[1])
        round_desc_list.append(desc_list[2])
        round_desc_list.append(desc_list[3])
        round_desc_list.append(desc_list[4])

        print(round_desc_list[0])

        print("\n5 inputs registered\n")
        
    return round_desc_list,num_i

if __name__=="__main__":

    while True:
        event_type = "input"
        round_desc_list,num_i = checkinputs() 
        break     
        
    print(round_desc_list[0])
```

This is the code which prints `round_desc_list[0]` inside `checkinputs()` in the else statement however it gives error in main after trying while loop.

```
desc1

5 inputs registered

Traceback (most recent call last):

    print(round_desc_list[0]) 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried to create a similar example to understand what's going wrong, however this code works and I do not get any error:

```py
import time

def iandj():

    i=0
    j=[]
    while i<10:
        j.append(i)
        i+=1
    return j,i

def fun():

    a = []
    j,i= iandj()

    time.sleep(5)

    if i % 2 !=0:
        fun()
    else:
        a.append(j[0])
        a.append(j[1])

    return a,i

if __name__=="__main__":

    while True:
        a,i = fun()
        break
        
    print(a[0])
    print(i)
```

```
0
10
```

I need help to understand why second code works and first gives error.

Comment: Your code can't be tested because it's incomplete.

Comment: When you recursively call `checkinputs()`, any data that it collected simply gets thrown away.  Each call to the function has entirely separate values for `desc_list` and all the other local variables.

Comment: @jasonharper Based on output it goes to else statement, successfully prints the list element and then return error for print statement outside function.

Comment: If you're getting IndexError when trying to access element 0 (zero) then the list is empty. Can you also explain why you're calling *sleep()* and also the strange *while True:* construct in the main program (albeit benign). Furthermore, a constant integer value in *iandj()* that is odd will lead to RecursionError

Comment: @Stuart I am using `while True:` and `sleep()` to call this function every few seconds until I get expected result required further in my code i.e. it goes to else statement

Answer (score 0):

I used [snoop](https://pypi.org/project/snoop/) for debugging and found that list was getting updated to empty eventually because execution did not stop after return statement:

```
5 inputs registered

02:59:44.71  169 |     return round_desc_list,num_i
02:59:44.75 <<< Return value from checkinputs: (["desc1", "desc2", "desc3", "desc4", "desc5"], 165)
02:59:44.75  157 |         checkinputs()
02:59:44.75  169 |     return round_desc_list,num_i
02:59:44.75 <<< Return value from checkinputs: ([], 161)
02:59:44.76  157 |         checkinputs()
02:59:44.77  169 |     return round_desc_list,num_i
02:59:44.77 <<< Return value from checkinputs: ([], 161)
02:59:44.78  157 |         checkinputs()
02:59:44.79  169 |     return round_desc_list,num_i
02:59:44.79 <<< Return value from checkinputs: ([], 161)
02:59:44.79  157 |         checkinputs()
02:59:44.80  169 |     return round_desc_list,num_i
02:59:44.80 <<< Return value from checkinputs: ([], 161)
[]
```

I am still trying to find the reason for this however fixed the error with a workaround by changing last 2 lines in `checkinputs()`:

```py
print("\n5 inputs registered\n")
return round_desc_list,num_i
return True
```